# How to remove space from RiTa.js random word generator?

Tags: javascript, processing, p5.js

I'm working on a word generator inspired by Daniel Shiffman's demo of the RiTa library. Right now, the code adds a space between all words and punctuation using the line:

```
output += " ";
```

I have been trying to figure out how to change the code so that space does not appear between punctuation (such as periods) and words. I think the simplest way to do this would be to use an if/else statement that leaves punctuation unaltered but adds space to words, but I am having a hard time figuring out [what functions from the Rita library to use for this](https://rednoise.org/rita/reference/index.php), as well as the syntax.

Any ideas? Here's my code right now:

```
var input;
var button;
var lexicon;

function setup() {
  noCanvas();
  lexicon = new RiLexicon();

  input = createInput('As I say a noun is the name of a thing.');
  button = createButton('submit');
  input.changed(processRita);
  button.mousePressed(processRita);
  input.size(400);
}

function processRita() {
var s = input.value();
var rs = new RiString(s);
var words = rs.words();
var pos = rs.pos();
console.log(words);
console.log(pos);

var output = '';

for (var i = 0; i < words.length; i++) { 
   if (/nn.*/.test(pos[i])) {
      var alliterations = lexicon.alliterations(words[i]);
      if(alliterations.length == 0){
        output+=words[i];
      }else{
         output += alliterations[Math.floor(Math.random() * alliterations.length)];
      }
      //console.log("noun");
      //console.log(alliterations.length);
    } else if (/jj.*/.test(pos[i])) {
      var alliterations = lexicon.alliterations(words[i]);
      output += alliterations[Math.floor(Math.random() * alliterations.length)];
      //console.log("adjective");
    } else if (/vb/.test(pos[i])) {
      var alliterations = lexicon.alliterations(words[i]);
      output += alliterations[Math.floor(Math.random() * alliterations.length)];
      //console.log("verbs");
    } 
    else {
      //console.log(words[i]);
      output += words[i];
  } {
       output += " ";
  }
  }
  createP(output);

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

after much trial and error, I had help from a coding professor who helped me to solve this problem, which was more complicated than I originally anticipated. In order to get this code to work, we added this bit toward the beginning of the for loop:

> if(words[i] == "." || words[i] == "," || words[i] == "?" || words[i] == "!"){
>       output += words[i];
>     }else{
>       output += " ";

So the entire code now looks like this:

```
for (var i = 0; i < words.length; i++) { 



if(words[i] == "." || words[i] == "," || words[i] == "?" || words[i] == "!"){
    output += words[i];
  }else{
    output += " ";
   if (/nn.*/.test(pos[i])) {
      var alliterations = lexicon.alliterations(words[i]);
      if(alliterations.length == 0){
        output+=words[i];
      }else{
         output += alliterations[Math.floor(Math.random() * alliterations.length)];
      }
      //console.log("noun");
      //console.log(alliterations.length);
    } else if (/jj.*/.test(pos[i])) {
      var alliterations = lexicon.alliterations(words[i]);
      output += alliterations[Math.floor(Math.random() * alliterations.length)];
      //console.log("adjective");
    } else if (/vb/.test(pos[i])) {
      var alliterations = lexicon.alliterations(words[i]);
      output += alliterations[Math.floor(Math.random() * alliterations.length)];
      //console.log("verbs");
    } 
    else {
      //console.log(words[i]);
      output += words[i];
  }

}


  }
  createP(output);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Why do you need a library for this? Can't you just use the regular `String` functions to test whether a `String` is a punctuation mark?

You could just use a regular expression to test whether a `String` matches a punctuation character. Or just use a series of equality checks against each punctuation mark you care about.

You might also check out [the `startsWith()` function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/startsWith) and [the `endsWith()` function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/endsWith).

Comment: >"You could just use a regular expression to test whether a String matches a punctuation character. Or just use a series of equality checks against each punctuation mark you care about." I was thinking about doing this, but I don't know how to set it up in the function. I tried various things but it either broke the code or made the spacing uneven (adding spaces only after the POS in the original code).

Answer (score 0):

Its *much* simpler if you use the [RiTa library](https://rednoise.org/rita/reference/index.php) functions:

```
function processRita() {

  var all, output = [],
    words = RiTa.tokenize(input.value()),
    pos = RiTa.getPosTags(words);

  for (var i = 0; i < words.length; i++) {
    if (/[nn|kk|vb|jj].*/.test(pos[i]) && (all = lexicon.alliterations(words[i])).length) {
      output.push(RiTa.randomItem(all));
    } else {
      output.push(words[i]);
    }
  }

  createP(RiTa.untokenize(output));
}
```